# existence of a number in (0,1) for ln(1+1/n)

Tags: analysis

Show that for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there is a numer $\theta_{n}$ where $0<\theta_{n}<1$
such that $log(1+ \frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{\theta_{n}}{2n^{2}}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\log(1+\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+\cdots$, can you prove any bounds using the first two terms?

Comment: The bounds are zero and 1 correct?

Comment: I was looking more for a bound on $\log(1+\frac{1}{n})$ based on $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}$